# d3.min / d3.max - getting values with related date

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm using d3.js for displaying some line-graphs based on a csv-file which holds the SERP-rankings for different keywords for each day.

The structure of the csv-file looks like this:

```
Keyword,Date,Google
Keyword1,2015/5/24,6
Keyword1,2015/5/25,6
Keyword1,2015/5/26,6
Keyword1,2015/5/27,6
Keyword1,2015/5/28,6
Keyword1,2015/5/29,6
Keyword1,2015/5/30,6
Keyword1,2015/5/31,6
Keyword1,2015/6/1,6
Keyword1,2015/6/2,6
Keyword1,2015/6/3,6
Keyword1,2015/6/4,6
Keyword1,2015/6/6,6
Keyword1,2015/6/7,6
Keyword1,2015/6/8,6
Keyword1,2015/6/9,6
Keyword1,2015/6/10,6
Keyword1,2015/6/11,6
Keyword1,2015/6/12,6
Keyword1,2015/6/13,6
Keyword1,2015/6/14,6
Keyword1,2015/6/16,6
Keyword1,2015/6/17,6
Keyword1,2015/6/18,6
Keyword1,2015/6/19,6
Keyword1,2015/6/20,6
Keyword1,2015/6/21,20
Keyword1,2015/6/22,20
Keyword1,2015/6/23,20
Keyword1,2015/6/24,20
Keyword1,2015/6/25,21
Keyword1,2015/6/26,21
Keyword1,2015/6/27,21
Keyword1,2015/6/28,21
Keyword1,2015/6/29,21
Keyword1,2015/6/30,21
Keyword1,2015/7/1,21
Keyword1,2015/7/2,21
Keyword1,2015/7/3,22
Keyword1,2015/7/4,22
Keyword1,2015/7/5,22
Keyword1,2015/7/6,22
Keyword1,2015/7/7,22
Keyword1,2015/7/8,22
Keyword1,2015/7/9,22
Keyword1,2015/7/10,22
Keyword1,2015/7/11,22
Keyword1,2015/7/12,22
Keyword1,2015/7/15,22
Keyword1,2015/7/16,21
Keyword1,2015/7/19,21
Keyword1,2015/7/20,21
Keyword1,2015/7/21,21
Keyword1,2015/7/22,21
Keyword1,2015/7/24,21
Keyword1,2015/7/25,20
Keyword1,2015/7/26,21
Keyword1,2015/7/27,21
Keyword1,2015/7/28,22
Keyword1,2015/7/29,20
Keyword1,2015/7/30,20
Keyword1,2015/7/31,20
Keyword1,2015/8/1,21
Keyword1,2015/8/3,22
Keyword1,2015/8/4,22
Keyword1,2015/8/5,18
Keyword1,2015/8/6,35
Keyword1,2015/8/7,5
Keyword1,2015/8/8,5
Keyword1,2015/8/9,3
Keyword1,2015/8/10,3
Keyword1,2015/8/11,3
Keyword1,2015/8/12,3
Keyword1,2015/8/13,3
Keyword1,2015/8/14,3
Keyword1,2015/8/15,3
Keyword1,2015/8/16,3
Keyword1,2015/8/16,6
Keyword2,2015/5/6,40
Keyword2,2015/5/7,39
Keyword2,2015/5/8,41
Keyword2,2015/5/9,41
Keyword2,2015/5/10,41
Keyword2,2015/5/11,48
Keyword2,2015/5/12,45
Keyword2,2015/5/13,44
Keyword2,2015/5/14,45
Keyword2,2015/5/15,49
Keyword2,2015/5/16,49
Keyword2,2015/5/17,91
Keyword2,2015/5/18,26
Keyword2,2015/5/19,27
Keyword2,2015/5/20,26
Keyword2,2015/5/21,55
Keyword2,2015/5/22,51
Keyword2,2015/5/23,51
Keyword2,2015/5/24,56
Keyword2,2015/5/25,26
Keyword2,2015/5/26,59
Keyword2,2015/5/27,59
Keyword2,2015/5/28,58
Keyword2,2015/5/29,58
Keyword2,2015/5/30,58
Keyword2,2015/5/31,53
Keyword2,2015/6/1,57
Keyword2,2015/6/2,56
Keyword2,2015/6/3,57
Keyword2,2015/6/4,59
Keyword2,2015/6/6,28
Keyword2,2015/6/7,54
Keyword2,2015/6/8,53
Keyword2,2015/6/9,51
Keyword2,2015/6/10,57
Keyword2,2015/6/11,59
Keyword2,2015/6/12,60
Keyword2,2015/6/13,55
Keyword2,2015/6/14,55
Keyword2,2015/6/16,55
Keyword2,2015/6/17,55
Keyword2,2015/6/18,59
Keyword2,2015/6/19,57
Keyword2,2015/6/20,59
Keyword2,2015/6/21,29
Keyword2,2015/6/22,27
Keyword2,2015/6/23,29
Keyword2,2015/6/24,29
Keyword2,2015/6/25,31
Keyword2,2015/6/26,28
Keyword2,2015/6/27,28
Keyword2,2015/6/28,27
Keyword2,2015/6/29,35
Keyword2,2015/6/30,35
Keyword2,2015/7/1,34
Keyword2,2015/7/2,29
Keyword2,2015/7/3,29
Keyword2,2015/7/4,25
Keyword2,2015/7/5,25
Keyword2,2015/7/6,27
Keyword2,2015/7/7,27
Keyword2,2015/7/8,27
Keyword2,2015/7/9,27
Keyword2,2015/7/10,30
Keyword2,2015/7/11,29
Keyword2,2015/7/12,29
Keyword2,2015/7/15,26
Keyword2,2015/7/16,25
Keyword2,2015/7/19,23
Keyword2,2015/7/20,27
Keyword2,2015/7/21,28
Keyword2,2015/7/22,28
Keyword2,2015/7/23,21
Keyword2,2015/7/24,21
Keyword2,2015/7/25,20
Keyword2,2015/7/26,20
Keyword2,2015/7/27,27
Keyword2,2015/7/28,26
Keyword2,2015/7/29,27
Keyword2,2015/7/30,20
Keyword2,2015/7/31,20
Keyword2,2015/8/1,21
Keyword2,2015/8/3,21
Keyword2,2015/8/4,21
Keyword2,2015/8/5,20
Keyword2,2015/8/6,19
Keyword2,2015/8/7,33
Keyword2,2015/8/8,30
Keyword2,2015/8/9,29
Keyword2,2015/8/10,29
Keyword2,2015/8/11,29
Keyword2,2015/8/12,26
Keyword2,2015/8/13,27
Keyword2,2015/8/14,37
Keyword2,2015/8/15,33
Keyword2,2015/8/16,36
Keyword2,2015/8/16,36
```

When I use some code the "normal" way, like I saw in my researches, everything works fine:

```
s.max = d3.max(s.values, function (d) {
    return d.Google;
})
s.min = d3.min(s.values, function (d) {
    return d.Google;
})
```

This works well and outputs this:

> Keyword1
>
> Best position: 3
>
> Worst position: 35
>
> Keyword2
>
> Best position: 19
>
> Worst position: 91

But this only outputs the Google-value.

**What I want to achieve is that the related "Date" to the found max-value gets displayed as well.**

So I tried it like this:

```
s.max = d3.max(s.values, function (d) {
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y");
    return d.Google + " (" + parseDate(d.Date) + ")";
})

s.min = d3.min(s.values, function (d) {
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y");
    return d.Google + " (" + parseDate(d.Date) + ")";
})
```

This looks nice at first. But the problem is, that sometimes the output isn't correct.

> Keyword1
>
> Best position: 18 (05-08-2015)
>
> Worst position: 6 (31-05-2015)
>
> Keyword2
>
> Best position: 19 (06-08-2015)
>
> Worst position: 91 (17-05-2015)

So as you can see, the output for Keyword2 is correct, but not for Keyword1 ,which should be :

> Keyword1
>
> Best position: 3 (09-08-2015)
>
> Worst position: 35 (06-08-2015)

I also tried it without the "parseDate", but this results in the same wrong output.

Can anyone tell me what is getting wrong here, why the output isn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the first example you are sorting numbers and in the second you are sorting strings. `3 < 21` and `"3" > "21"` are both true. It's not the most efficient approach in the world, but I'd say just sort your array by number and then grab the first and last elements. Something like:

```
var sorted = s.values.map(function(d) { return d; }).sort(function(a,b) {
  return b.Google - a.Google;
});

// Note: I can never remember if Array.sort is ascending or descending by default. Use with caution.
var max = sorted[0].Google + " (" + formatDate(sorted[0].Date) + ")";
var min = sorted[sorted.length - 1].Google + " (" + formatDate(sorted[sorted.length - 1].Date) + ")";
```

Then do whatever you want to build your displayed string based on min/max.

Comment: Hi @Ethan! Thx for your reply! I added your sort function first below my s.max/s.min call, but then the graph gets drawn "wrong" (from left to right instead from top to bottom). So I first switched to `return b.Google - a.Google` which kinda had the same effect. Then I tried to use a.Date or b.Date which made strange graphs. Then I added your new var max/var min lines, but with no effect (changed my variable-placeholders from s.min to min). I also tried this before and after my d.min/d.max-call, but both didn't help.

Comment: The .sort function changes your s.values array in place. So you'll probably want to copy the array first. I'm updating the example also to show how to calculate the mins and maxes as you wanted. If you are still having problems, please take some time to create a working example that we can modify.

Comment: Hi there! And thx for your reply again! I tried your edited answer as well, but I couldn't get it to work like it should. Meanwhile I also tried to create a working fiddle, but this lacks somehow. In my fiddle the graph is missing and the **wrong values** get displayed **each time - regardless if I choose the first or the second example** - here's the fiddle link, maybe this helps somehow...[link](http://jsfiddle.net/mot4ox7p/3/) http://jsfiddle.net/mot4ox7p/3/

Comment: You just hadn't converted your values after parsing in the CSV. Here's a working version with my suggestion included (lines 40 - 50): https://jsfiddle.net/5m56do4b/2/

Comment: Thx again for yor afford on this! But I think this is going into a wrong direction. I implemented your lines of code 40-50 in my working-live-testsurrounding and I got the max and min possible value of "Google" which results in 1 for min and 100 for max. But this is not what I wanted. And the "functions"? d3.min.... and d3.max already do what I want, but without getting the associated/related date. I've got another nest-call, which creates this output: `{"key":"keyword1","values":{"max":"64 - 25-06-2015","min":"38 - 04-08-2015"}}`  But I have no idea how I can access/output these values...

Comment: This is the " nest-call": `var expenseMetrics = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Keyword; }) 
  .rollup(function(v) { return {
    max: d3.max(v, function(d) { var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y"); return d.Google + " - " + parseDate(d.Date); }),
    min: d3.min(v, function(d) { var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y"); return d.Google + " - " + parseDate(d.Date); })
  };  
 })
  .entries(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(expenseMetrics));`

Comment: Please update the working example and explain how it differs from what you would like to see. If you have questions about d3.nest, you might want to bring that up in another question as it is a different topic.